# Multiple Levels of Avg of Averages needed in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Starting out with initial data in this form:

TABLE1

```
PARENT         BRAND      SUB BRAND   AVG INCREASE
PARENT ONE     BRAND ONE     1           9.90%
PARENT ONE     BRAND ONE     2           8.70%
PARENT ONE     BRAND ONE     3           5.00%
PARENT TWO     BRAND TWO     4           4.90%
PARENT TWO     BRAND THREE   5           9.50%
PARENT TWO     BRAND FOUR    6           4.90%
PARENT TWO     BRAND FIVE    7           4.90%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SIX     8         -96.90%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SIX     9         -50.00%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SIX     10        -33.00%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SEVEN   11        -70.00%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SEVEN   12        -89.00%
```

1) I am using TABLE1 to calculate Avg of Average Increase by PARENT with the following:

```
PARENT AVG = 
AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE (
        TABLE1,
        TABLE1[PARENT],
        TABLE1[BRAND],
        "Brand Average", AVERAGE (TABLE1[AVG INCREASE] )
    ),
    [Brand Average]
)
```

To get the following:

```
PARENT         BRAND          AVG INCREASE
PARENT ONE     BRAND ONE       7.87%
PARENT TWO     BRAND TWO       4.90%
PARENT TWO     BRAND THREE     9.50%
PARENT TWO     BRAND FOUR      4.90%
PARENT TWO     BRAND FIVE      4.90%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SIX     -59.97%
PARENT THREE   BRAND SEVEN   -79.50%
```

How would I go about getting the overall AVG of PARENT?

It should be the avg of each parent:

```
PARENT ONE    7.87%
PARENT TWO    6.05%
PARENT THREE  -69.74
```

**AVG OF PARENTS = -18.61%**

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the same process, but add a level:

```
AvgIncrease =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        Table1[Parent],
        "Parent Avg", AVERAGEX (
            SUMMARIZE (
                TABLE1,
                TABLE1[PARENT],
                TABLE1[BRAND],
                "Brand Average", AVERAGE ( TABLE1[AVG INCREASE] )
            ),
            [Brand Average]
        )
    ),
    [Parent Avg]
)
```

If you save your `[PARENT AVG]` formula as a measure, you can use it inside another measure like this:

```
AvgIncrease =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        Table1[Parent],
        "Parent Average", [PARENT AVG]
    ),
    [Parent Average]
)
```